# Open old presumably Prolog "db"-file

Tags: database, binary, prolog

I've got a binary ".db"-file which dates year 2000. I've been told it is a Prolog database.
Is there any way I can view it/export the contents to text?

If I open it with a text editor, several first lines are:
      H ]  ]] ]G       Ц
?   4    я я    ‰e xЗЗ  ]                   ц               kdN(6 0  b$       #

## (######ДЗЗ$З(З/З3З:ЗIЗYЗnЗ{З€З’З З¬З»ЗЗЗТЗЫЗжЗтЗЗЗЗ$З2ЗEЗRЗ_ЗnЗЃЗ€З—ЗЄЗёЗЛЗУЗЭЗбЗцЗ    ЗЗ1З;ЗGЗUЗ]ЗdЗjЗoЗuЗ~ЗЌЗRESTTEMP.DB                                                                    Ќ бҐ«Ґ­­л© Їг­Єв ”€Ћ  ­ЄҐв  Ї®« ­ ж-вм ¬Ґбв® а®¦¤Ґ­Ёп ¬Ґбв®¦ЁвҐ«мбвў® б Є Є®Ј® Ј®¤  ў Ї®б. Ј®¤ а®¦¤Ґ­Ёп ¬Ґбв® а Ў®вл ¤®«¦­®бвм бЇҐжЁ «м­®бвм ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ ­ ж-вм бгЇагЈ  а®¤­®© п§лЄ ў®бЇЁв ­ЁҐ ”€Ћ ®вж  а®¤®¬ ®вҐж ­ ж-вм ®вж  а®¤­®© п§лЄ ®вж  п§лЄЁ ®вж  ”€Ћ ¬ вҐаЁ а®¤®¬ ¬ вм ­ ж-вм ¬ вҐаЁ а®¤­®© п§лЄ ¬ вҐаЁ п§лЄЁ ¬ вҐаЁ п§лЄ ¤Ґвбвў  п§лЄ ­ з.иЄ®«л п§лЄ баҐ¤­Ґ© иЄ®«л а Ў®в  ­ ж-вм б®бҐ¤Ґ© ®ЎйҐ­ЁҐ б б®бҐ¤п¬Ё ­ ж-вм ¤аг§Ґ© ®ЎйҐ­ЁҐ б ¤аг§мп¬Ё ¬ Ј §Ё­ бҐ«мб®ўҐв ”ЂЏ ®ЎйҐ­ЁҐ б а®¤ЁвҐ«п¬Ё ®ЎйҐ­ЁҐ б бгЇагЈ®¬ ®ЎйҐ­ЁҐ

Comment: What do you get when you try to open it in a text editor? Can you post the first lines?

Comment: Prolog doesn't natively have a standard binary database file format. If someone told you this is a prolog DB, they were wrong. `.db` is somewhat generic in that there are a couple of databases that use it, one of them being Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for telling me it is not presumably a Prolog Database.
I've consulted the guys, and it's finally turned out it's a Borland Paradox database, so I've used a free program to export it to csv.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a standard "Prolog database" binary format.

Try [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command. It knows a lot of file signatures and may recognize your file.